# Shared memory is not updated

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, shared-memory

I have two processes, talking with each other using memory mapped file and named event. Initialization code is the same in both processes. Error handling is not shown here, but I check all return values.

```
HANDLE m_hFileMapping;
LPVOID m_pViewOfFile;
int* m_pDataPtr;
HANDLE m_hEventDone;

m_hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,           // system paging file
    NULL,                           // security attributes
    PAGE_READWRITE,                 // protection
    0,                              // high-order DWORD of size
    MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE_SIZE,        // low-order DWORD of size (4096)
    MEMORY_MAPPED_FILE_NAME);       // name (the same for both processes)


m_pViewOfFile = MapViewOfFile(
    m_hFileMapping,             // handle to file-mapping object
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,        // desired access
    0,
    0,
    0);                         // map all file

m_pDataPtr = (int*)m_pViewOfFile;

m_hEventDone = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, EVENT_NAME_COMMAND_DONE);   // the same name in both processes
```

Server process updates shared memory and sets event:

```
*m_pDataPtr = some_value;
SetEvent(m_hEventDone);
```

Client process waits for `m_hEventDone`. Once event is set, it reads the memory:

```
if ( WaitForSingleObject(m_hEventDone, TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
{
     // handle error and return
}

int result = *m_pDataPtr;
```

Sometimes client process reads an old (previous) value from `m_pDataPtr`. On the next iteration it can read updated value. Both programs are in Debug configuration, no optimizations. They run on Windows 7 multicore computer. Access to shared memory is not synchronized, because read/write transactions are initiated by user command and serialized.

How can I change this program to get the latest updated value on the client side?

Comment: `volatile` will prevent the compiler from generating code that caches a variable's value or reading it from the cache. Instead, the value is read from memory.

Comment: @IInspectable: defining pointer as volatile solved the problem. Post this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compiler can optimize code in a way that does not change the observed behavior. It does so by analyzing the code at hand. It is free to emit instructions that cache values in registers or reorder instructions, if it deduces that they are unrelated. This is safe as long as the compiler sees all accesses to memory.

In an environment where memory can change in *unusual* ways, the compiler has no way of knowing. Examples are hardware register accesses or I/O-mapped memory locations, where memory can change outside the program a compiler sees. To prevent the compiler from making any assumptions about an object the [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx) keyword is available in C and C++. The result is that a compiler will not perform any optimizations or reorder instructions when accessing the object.

To solve your problem you have to mark all data that resides in shared memory as `volatile`. This guarantees that both processes will always see the same data. It also ensures that the value of an object is written immediately on assignment.